# ng-repeat not adding new items dynamically

Tags: angularjs, socket.io, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to Angular JS (1) and I am having issues with ng-repeat. I am using socket.io with Angular. Here is my controller:

```
var messagingApp = angular.module('messagingApp', []);

function mainController($scope) {

    var socket = io.connect();
    socket.on('message', function(data){
        $scope.users.push({'Name': 'yeh'});
        console.log($scope.users);
    });

    $scope.users = []; //if I put stuff here and comment out socket stuff, it shows in the front-end
};

messagingApp.controller('mainController',mainController);
```

I can see that it is going inside that on block (via console.log). However, it is not displaying anything to the front-end. My front-end is as follows:

```
<body ng-controller="mainController">

<div ng-repeat="user in users">
    <p>{{ user.Name }}</p>
</div>
```

My understanding is that if you change the model (users in this case), it should automatically update the ng-repeat. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Add $scope.$apply() after pushing to the array.

Comment: @Raj Yes that was it! Post it as a proper answer and I'll accept it. So what is $apply. Does it notify the front-end that something in the model has changed? Do we $apply only when doing async stuff or anytime whenever a model is changed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add $scope.$apply() after pushing to the array. Because you are updating the model outside of the angular scope. So the angularjs doesnot know the model has been updated. More about $scope.$apply http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/watch-digest-apply.html

Answer (score 0):

you are pushing the object in array and try to iterate Array. So you should specify the position.

```
<body ng-controller="mainController">
    <div ng-repeat="user in users">
        <p>{{ user[$index].Name }}</p>
    </div>
```

or try this..

```
socket.on('message', function(data){
         $scope.users.data.push({'Name': 'yeh'});
        console.log($scope.users.data);
    });

     $scope.users = {data:[]};





<div ng-repeat="user in users.data">
        <p>{{ user.Name }}</p>
    </div>
```