# ng-repeat not working with large set of data

Tags: html, angularjs, performance, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have to print (say 100000 rows) in the HTML page. These rows are coming from a socket connection providing a transfer speed of around 500-700 rows per second, and all of them needs to be appended to the HTML body. ng-repeat is appending all rows only when the socket connection is paused, that too it takes a minimum of 4-5 seconds to append even 2000 records.
I cant use pagination, lazyloading nothing, it needs to be on the same page, all loaded at once.
Need help with it.

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41179103/ng-repeat-not-adding-new-items-dynamically

Comment: Have tried it, didn't work. $spply makes the browser freeze!

Comment: ^ `$scope.$apply()` would call a digest cycle, updating the model and re-check any **watchers**. With 100k results, this will _melt_ your website. So I would remove any two-way data-binding -
 `{{ data }}` or `ng-model`, and replace them with one-way - `{{:: data }}` or `ng-bind`

Answer (score 0):

`ng-repeat` is always slow if you have more data to display, I can suggest you few options.

1- Go for client side infinite scroll option with `ng-repeat`, you can check [this](https://sroze.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/demo_basic.html) for more details.

2- You can use  `$interval` to append the collection with a number of records which gets binded to the ng-repeat.

3- Try replacing the ng-repeat with a grid control  which supports virtualization.